# Lambda SQS integration: Batch Size vs MaxBatchingWindow

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm integrating a lambda function with a standard queue in SQS.

I came across these two parameters `batchSize` and `maxBatchingWindow`. My original thinking was either the number of messages in the queue has reached the `batchSize` or the time since the first message came in has last for `maxBatchingWindow` seconds will trigger the lambda. In other words, whichever condition is satisfied first will invoke the lambda. And I couldn't find enough clarification about these two parameters in this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).

As a result, I did some experiment, setting `batchSize = 3` and `maxBatchingWindow = 300 seconds` while setting the `reservedConcurrency = 1` for lambda. Then I manually create 3 messages in the queue quickly (<< 5 min). However, I didn't observe the lambda being invoked after 5 minutes (300 s). Particularly, the metric `Number Of Messages Sent` of sqs shows a new data point at `xx:54:15` while the logGroup for lambda updates around `xx:59:53` (The lambda does nothing intensive but just to print out the value of `event` so I'm sure that would be the right execution).

Does that mean, once `maxBatchingWindow` is set greater than 0, it will become the only requirement to invoke lambda even if the `batchSize` has met?

Comment: "I didn't observe the lambda being invoked after 5 minutes". When did you observe the lambda being invoked?

Comment: I've updated the follow in my description: Particularly, the metric `Number Of Messages Sent` of sqs shows `xx:54:15` while the logGroup for lambda updates around `xx:59:53` (The lambda does nothing intensive but just to print out the value of `event`).